# in win10, how to disable disable/block the 'bottom bar'/taskbar without disabling other basic functions/stuff about the os that are commonly used

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

in win10,

how to disable disable/block the 'bottom bar'/taskbar without disabling other basic functions/stuff about the os that are commonly used

as you know, this is the design problem:

'Can anyone tell me if it is possible at all to hide the dock permanently (so that it never shows up)? ...having continuously to be careful not to bump on the dock unnecessarily.

And, the Dock does pop up all the time, sometimes repeatedly. very annoying! If the Dock is at the bottom and I try to reach the bottom of a window, popping-up comes the dock. If I place the Dock vertically, while I try to reach the HD or my desktop, popping up comes the dock. Not to mention when I click on an application which I do not wish to open, I just have to sit and wait it open just to quick it. Too much time consuming dealing with the dock...

this is from someone in 2009 -- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2114879

instead of explaining it again, i just quote it cos it's good. i typically/usually just link, but quoted it to help out

here's how i'd explain it tho:

- the bar at the bottom in macos, win10 and anything else that does it this way is bad (cos it prevents & hinders the free use of the mouse)
- aka: desktops do not use space (and i pray for the golden days of computing AR)

Comment: Image would help explain what you want to display.  Taskbar is to generic.  Edit your question and be sure to use “Upload Image”.  The thread linked to a video, if you can’t describe what you want yourself, 2009 is ancient when it comes to Windows

Comment: the entire 'bottom bar'/taskbar

Comment: You can configure the taskbar to automatically hide itself but by default default what you want cannot be accomplished with the default Windows shell.  Taskbar has never prevented the use of my mouse.

Comment: To push home a point.  The YouTube video can’t even be seen and the thread had absolutely no content.

Comment: well it appears to so far that what is asked cannot be done on win10/macos, tho i edited the post a bit anyhow so that others that have not experienced the problem first-hand would have a better understanding of what is meant by 'prevents you from using your mouse freely' - this was also explained well enough by the person that asked the question on that link

Comment: The linked question was about an Apple OS your asking about Windows.  I don’t see the connection, and the solution, to that question was a video that can’t be viewed.  Thus the reason I asked for a screenshot.

Comment: while it seems like there isn't going to be any more good answers within the next year or more for this since the regularly active users likely have seen this already, just for fun and clarifications, the connection is all similar questions are asking about the same exact thing or similar patterned things regardless of anything else. anyone that has experienced this first-hand or just has the relevant basic knowledge easily can tell. the knowledge of what this is about is good ux/ui/hci/design just basic things about using an os well pretty much

Comment: also where to go ask about sofware/app recommendations for various things? this site is likely not good for it

Comment: also you cant take pics/images of something anyone doesnt know how to do, or possibly is impossible (which at least 2 ppl so far said is impossible)

Comment: You can supply a screenshot with an arrow.  Visual aids are helpful

Comment: what screenshot software you recommend i download? that would do what you're asking? never done those things before

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the taskbar completely unless you disable the whole Explorer shell.

However, you could try the workaround:

1. Hide taskbar

Settings-> Personalization -> Taskbar -> turn on "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode", if  you using tablet mode, turn on next "Automatically  hide the taskbar in tablet mode".

2. Move the taskbar to top, right or left of screen

Settings-> Personalization -> Taskbar -> Taskbar location on screen

[image]

Comment: while it seems that this cant be done, what did you use to annotate your screenshot